Laravel 11 : QR code not appear in email when i sent email
I am trying to generate QR codes on the fly when sending emails using gmail smtp and Laravel 11. At first the QR code was not generated, it was always blank, then I tried the recommendation from this question: QR code not appear in email when i sent email. Although I am converted it to img.
My QR code is still not visible. Any advise or recommendations of what I can read to get the correct format of a scannable code will be appreciated. Its currently being generated as part of an attachment.
Here is my class :
class ConfirmAttendance extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $name;
    private $id;

    public function __construct($name, $id)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function envelope(): Envelope
    {
        return new Envelope(
            subject: 'Ticket Information!',
        );
    }

    public function content(): Content
    {
        $qrCodeAsPng = QrCode::format('png')->size(500)->generate($this->id);
        $qrCodeBase64 = base64_encode($qrCodeAsPng);

        return new Content(
            view: 'mail.confirm-attendance',
            with: [
                'name' => $this->name,
                'id' => $this->id,
                'qrCodeBase64' => $qrCodeBase64,
            ],
        );
    }

    public function attachments(): array
    {
        $qrCodeAsPng = QrCode::format('png')->size(500)->generate($this->id);
        $attachmentName = 'qr_code.png';

        return [
            \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Attachment::fromData(
                fn() => $qrCodeAsPng,
                $attachmentName,
                'image/png'
            ),
        ];
    }
}

Here is my blade template :
<p>Dear {{ $name }},</p>

<p>Congratulations! We're thrilled to have you join us for this exciting event!</p>

<h3>Your Ticket QR Code:</h3>

<div>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ $qrCodeBase64 }}" alt="QR Code" />
</div>

<p>Ticket ID: {{ $id }}</p>

<br />


What is the QR code library you are using?  Your code here doesn't show it - have you imported it correctly in your Mailable class?  Have you tried to see what $qrCodeAsPng looks like when generated in the Mailable, does it work at all?  If you view the source of your email, what does $qrCodeBase64 look like?  Have you checked Larvel and PHP logs?

Why dont you render it in your email template without attaching it with email?
